# "Je ne sais pas quoi demander" vs "Je ne sais pas ce que demander"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-interrogatifs

Is "quoi" here:

> Je ne sais pas quoi demander

just an informal way of saying "ce que"?

Shouldn't it be:

> Je ne sais pas ce que demander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il y a deux formulations possibles :

> - Je ne sais pas quoi demander.
> - Je ne sais pas ce que je dois/peux demander.

Réponse au commentaire, « se souvenir » est un verbe transitif indirect, le complément est introduit par « de », on dira plutôt :

> Je me souviens **de** ce que je dois faire.

Pour répondre aux autres interrogations en commentaires, dans ce type de construction, « quoi » sera suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif, et « ce que » par une proposition subordonnée. Comme indiqué dans les deux premières phrases.

Comment: Pourquoi c'est ainsi? Donc je ne peux pas dire quelque chose comme ça? "Ce que" faut-il qu'il soit suivi par un clause? Est "quoi", l'utilise-on quand il n'y a qu'une verbe suivante? Donc je ne peux pas dire "Je me souviens ce que faire" et je dois plutôt dire "Je me souviens quoi faire"?

Comment: @BlobGod: See my edit.

Comment: Ça ne m'aide pas, s'il vous plaît, répondez à ma question.

Comment: J'ai demandé ceci: ce que faut-il être suivi par un clause, et quoi, peut seulement être suivi par un verbe?