# Excepting "savoir", how does "quoi" function as a general second negator?

Tags: négation

Outwith [je ne sais quoi](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7607) and *savoir*, how does "ne quoi" function? Can you negate other verbs with "ne quoi"? Here are some examples.

Can misanthropes exclaim "je ne connais quoi", because they don't care about *connaitre* other people?

What if you're anesthetized or numb, and can't feel anything? Can you proclaim "je ne sens quoi" or "je ne ressens quoi"?

What if you're too tired to think? Can you proclaim "je ne pense quoi"?

What if you're stuffed, and can't eat or drink anymore? Can you proclaim "je ne bouffe quoi"? "Je ne picole/sirote quoi"?

> #### 23.2.1.1 General negation

> The main general negator is *pas*, whose use in clause negation is illustrated
> in (1) and (5)–(8) above. In addition, the items *guère, point, nullement*, and
> *aucunement* may be used, particularly in more formal registers.

[image]

Hansen, *The structure of modern standard French* (2016), pp 311-2.

Comment: @livresque Did you even read my post?  I linked to that post in mine.

Comment: I didn't register the link, pardon.  Perhaps this is of more help : http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=3743435700 and https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the question, nevertheless I'll try to point something out so you can rephrase it.  *Quoi* doesn't function with *ne*, it's not part of the negation, so it can't be grammatically or semantically compared to *pas, point*, etc. *Quoi* is a pronoun (object to *sais*) and you could have *je ne sais où*, *je ne sais comment*, etc... No, we could not have  ? "*je ne connais quoi*"   because *pas* can't be omitted with *connaitre*, only very few verbs accept the ommision of *pas*, *point*.. (from memory: *avoir, pouvoir, oser, cesser, daigner*, list to be checked).

Comment: @None "*Quoi* doesn't function with *ne*, it's not part of the negation". I think you pinpointed my worriment! "Je ne sais quoi" led me to think that *quoi* is part of the negation with *ne*! Can you explain pls how "je ne sais quoi" works, if *quoi* doesn't function with *ne*?

Comment: @livresque That's OK. Can you please remove your comment that flags this as duplicate?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19740/358) deals with it, so I'm not keen on writing a new one. Concerning the use of *quoi* here you might consider that *je ne sais pas quoi* and *je ne sais quoi* are exactly the same thing and focus on the meaning of *quoi/ce que*. If your question is a duplicate it is in no way to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7607/358). You might consider marking my earlier comment as useful so that it appears on top of the list of comments and avoid more people asking for the question to be closed for a wrong reason.

Comment: @livresque Nowhere in his question is the OP asking about the omission of *pas* or about the split negative.

Comment: "Je ne sais quoi" is a relic of a late Old French/early Middle French construction. The type of negation used (with ne alone) is simply what was in use at the time. In French, the evolution didn't go beyond set expression, but in Eastern Oil languages those became indefinite pronouns, leaking sometimes into the regional French of those places (Vous voulez ène sakwé (=quelque chose) à boire?), showing quite nicely how frozen and unanalyzed they've become

Comment: "Excepting “savoir”, how does “quoi” function as a general second negator?" This title has a big problem. Quoi does **not** function a a general second negator : we also use the same sentence without omitting the *pas* : "je ne sais pas quoi". You can't do that with *guère, jamais, nullement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Quoi* is only used as "pseudo second negator" with the verb *savoir*. I write "pseudo" because there is actually kind of an implicit *pas* in this construction, [unlike the negations with guère, jamais, nullement, etc](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/excepting-savoir-how-does-quoi-function-as-a-general-second-negator/46638#comment93197_46636) where there can't be a *pas*.

None of your attemps with a different verb would work.

*Quoi* can be used in negative statements but never as a negator:

> — *Je mange pas de [inaudible].*
> — *Tu manges pas quoi ?*

Here *quoi* is a pronoun replacing something that wasn't heard or understood.

Note that your question was legitimate. While a native French "knows" what can be a co-negator and what can't, there is no obvious difference at first sight between *je ne vois **personne*** and *je ne sais **quoi***.

In early French, the first occurences of *je ne vois personne* were technically built like "I don't see [a] person" and *je ne sais quoi*. That's only after time that *personne* split into two words belonging to different categories, one still a positive substantive (*Une personne*, someone) and another generally negative, the pronoun *personne* (nobody) but sometimes still positive (anyone).

Such a split never happened with ***quoi***, so it stays a "positive" pronoun even in *je ne sais quoi* (I don't know what) and accepts a true co-negator like ***pas*** or ***plus***:

> *Je ne sais pas quoi.*

> *Je ne sais plus quoi.*

With personne, ***pas*** is excluded (or at best, reverses the meaning) :

> **Je ne vois pas personne.* (*I don't see nobody)

but ***plus*** is fine:

> *Je ne vois plus personne.* (I don't see anyone anymore)

Comment: Je ne dirais pas que « quoi » ici fait partie de la négation ("second negator"), pas plus que « où » (*je ne sais où il va*)  ou « comment » (*je ne sais comment réagir*). Ils introduisent  une complétive, non ? (? parce que pas sûr..)

Comment: @None Je dis la même chose, mais peut-être ne suis-je pas assez clair. *Quoi* peut être utilisé dans une phrase négative mais sans faire partie de la négation proprement dite.

Comment: Je commentais sur « *Quoi* is only used as second negator with the verb savoir ». Et je disais que je n'étais pas d'accord avec cette formulation qui est celle du PO et qui semble le point d'achoppement de son problème.

Comment: @None Ah, d'accord. Je comprends mieux la discussion maintenant.

Answer (score 2):

*Quoi* is not part of the negation, it doesn't function with *ne*, it can't be grammatically nor semantically compared to *pas, point, nullement, guère,* etc.

In the sentence *je ne sais quoi dire* the negation is *ne...pas* where *pas* is omitted. The answers to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/26715/358) might help you go further with the omission of *pas*.

*Quoi* introduces a dependent clause, it is a pronoun, it is the direct object of the verb *dire*.

The use of *quoi* depends on what follows in the sentence.

- Je ne sais (pas) quoi dire.
- Je sais quoi dire.

If *dire* had a subject then you could not use *quoi*, you would use *ce que*:

- Je ne sais (pas) ce qu'il dit.
- Je sais ce qu'il a dit.

You could also have :

- Je ne sais (pas) où aller.
- Je ne sais (pas) comment dire ça.

Although *savoir* is not the only verb with which *pas* can be omitted in a negative sentence, I think it is the only one in the list which  admits *quoi* (or *ce que*) to introduce the following dependent clause.

[This page](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/ne-litteraire/) has a list of the verbs that can omit *pas*.

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote this question, I knew  that *pas* can be omitted as the second negator. I just didn't know that *pas* was omitted in the case of "je ne sais quoi".